# ¿mostrar resultado en un input type= text?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Me dirijo a ustedes porque tengo el siguiente problema: estoy haciendo un conversor de numero decimal a Binario, tengo una función en JavaScript  que convierte el numero decimal a Binario, primero estoy realizando una validación para verificar que el numero que me pasen en la entrada no sea negativo o cero y estoy enviando un alert hasta aquí no hay problemas, pero cuando quiero meter la lógica para que convierta el numero de decimal a binario y lo muestre en el input text

```js
function convertirABinario() {
    var decimal = document.getElementById('decimal').value
    if(decimal < 0 || decimal == 0) {
        alert('Tanto los numero negativos como el cero no se puden convertir a Binario');
        console.log('Tanto los numero negativos como el cero no se puden convertir a Binario')
    }    
    if(decimal == 1) {
        document.getElementsByName('resultadoBinario')[0].value = 1;
    }else {
        var decimal = document.getElementsById('decimal');
        var array = [];
        while(num > 0) {
            array.unshift(decimal % 2);
            decimal = Math.floor(decimal / 2); // rendondea el numero al entero mas bajo ej: 12.5 ---> 12.
        }         
    }
    document.getElementsByName('resultadoBinario')[0].value = array;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Convertidor de numeros</title>
    <!--Framework para utilizar Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
    <script src="conversor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculadora Binaria</h1>   
    <hr>
    <p>
        Convierte facilmente cualquier cifra decimal en una cifra binaria con nuestra Calculadora
        conversora Binaria online.
    </p> 
    <div class="container" >
        <h2>Convertir numero decimal a Binario</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- Entrada del numero decimal--> 
  
        <label for="">Numero decimal</label>
        <input type="text" id='decimal'>
        <hr>
        <label for="">Numero Binario</label>
        <input type="text" id="binario" name="resultadoBinario">
        <hr>
 
    <input type="button" value="Convertir" onclick="convertirABinario()">     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mueve tu `document.getElementsByName('resultadoBinario')[0].value = array;` dentro del bloque `else` de lo contrario siempre se ejecutará. Y tampoco estas agregando nada a tu `array`. debes de poner `array.push(decimal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes numerosos errores de sintaxis al llamar a las funciones del document. Estás escribiendo `document.getElementsById` con una s. La función con la s no existe, es `document.getElementById`.

Por otro lado tu algoritmo de conversión tiene bastantes problemas... num no está definido y no parece haber señal de esa variable en tu código. Tus operaciones se realizan en decimal, y no veo que realices nunca la conversión de string a number.

Arreglar tu código sin saber exactamente que tenías en mente cuando lo escribiste me parece un poco complicado. Te propongo una solución con la función de number `toString(2)`, que te hace la conversión a binario.

Te dejo un código funcional:

```js
function convertirABinario() {
    var decimal = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('decimal').value)
    if(decimal < 0) {
        alert('Los numero negativos no se puden convertir a Binario');
    }else{
    document.getElementById('binario').value = decimal.toString(2) ;}
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Convertidor de numeros</title>
    <!--Framework para utilizar Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
    <script src="conversor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculadora Binaria</h1>   
    <hr>
    <p>
        Convierte facilmente cualquier cifra decimal en una cifra binaria con nuestra Calculadora
        conversora Binaria online.
    </p> 
    <div class="container" >
        <h2>Convertir numero decimal a Binario</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- Entrada del numero decimal--> 
  
        <label for="">Numero decimal</label>
        <input type="number" id='decimal'>
        <hr>
        <label for="">Numero Binario</label>
        <input type="number" id="binario" name="resultadoBinario">
        <hr>
 
    <input type="button" value="Convertir" onclick="convertirABinario()">     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Jaime, Tienes mucha razón tengo bastante errores de sintaxis y el algoritmo no estaba funcional, Muchas gracias por tu respuesta fue de muchísima ayuda.

Comment: @rafaprieto me alegra te sirva. Puedes programar tu función propia de convertir a binario, y cuando la tengas lista, sustituyes `decimal.toString(2)` por `miFuncion(decumal)`. ¡Buena suerte!